# Redirect back when login successful Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, redirect, authentication, back, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to redirect the user to the previous page after login.

In my blade page I've,

```
@if(Auth::check())
    {{ $products->phone }}
@else
    <a href="{{ url('log')}}"> </a> //url to login page
@endif
```

Before that I'm creating a session so that I can know that the request is from the above blade page.

My controller:

```
public function log(){
    Session::flash('log_msg', 'login needed!'); 
    return view('my_account');
}
```

When I put the condition like `if(Session::has(log_msg)){//redirect back}` in the Login Controller it  throws an error.

Now I'm confused where to put the condition. Can anyone tell me where I can put the condition in Logincontroller or in Middelware and how?

Comment: why don't you use laravel built in login? it has all this thing, using intended method you can redirect user to directly previous page which he was trying to access before login head over to here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication
and intended method can be seen here
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: What is the error thrown in login controller?

Comment: We do not know what you are doing in your controllers, but I'm afraid you are using the Session::flash method that is valid ONLY during the next request. If you have to request in the middle, you will not have any session variable. And of course, if you do not have an else clause to return something, laravel will raise an error...

Answer (score 0):

You can change redirect route in your AuthController.php 
Change /home to your route.

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

And it should work.